# Get text from select <p> onclick

Tags: jquery, onclick

Have a link div, with two `<p>` sections, on link click I only want to get the text of the first `<p>`.

My code is below:-

HTML

```
<div id="link">
    <a href="#another-div" class="link">
        <div class="class-name">
            <p>Value I want to get</p>
            <p>This value I don't need</p>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Output div:-

```
<div id="another-div">
    <label id="output-val"></label>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
j$(document).ready(function() {
    j$("#link a").click(function() {
        var text = j$(this).text();
        j$("#output-val").text(text);
    } 
});
```

This gets the value of both `<p>`'s, how do I only get the first one?

Comment: There's a lot of similar questions available try to search first. please do google first.

Comment: you are missing `)` in your script code in second-last `}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are missing `)` in your script code in second-last `}`

Change your code like below (use `find('p:first')`):-

```
j$(document).ready(function() {
    j$("#link a").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var text = j$(this).find('p:first').text();//find first p text
        j$("#output-val").text(text);
    });//missing )  here 
});
```

Working example:-

```js
var j$ = $;
j$(document).ready(function() {
    j$("#link a").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var text = j$(this).find('p:first').text();
      j$("#output-val").text(text);
    }); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="link">
    <a href="#another-div" class="link">
        <div class="class-name">
            <p>Value I want to get</p>
            <p>This value I don't need</p>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>

<div id="another-div">
    <label id="output-val"></label>
</div>
```

Reference:- [jQuery :first Selector](https://api.jquery.com/first-selector/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `:first` to get the first element of any tag.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#link a").click(function() {
        var text = $(this).find("p:first").text();
        $("#output-val").text(text);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="link">
    <a href="#another-div" class="link">
        <div class="class-name">
            <p>Value I want to get</p>
            <p>This value I don't need</p>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>

<div id="another-div">
    <label id="output-val"></label>
</div>
```